# Dealing with enums implementing common interface (iterate, deserialize)

Tags: java, interface, enums, enumset

I have an Android application that loads a data from web sources and displays it. I organized each API method those sources support in enum constants split per source. Let's say, SourceA provides Sport and Weather data and SourceB provides Stock and News data.

```
public enum ServiceA implements ServiceMethod {
    GET_SPORT(...) {...}, 
    GET_WEATHER(...) {...};
    ...
}

public enum ServiceB implements ServiceMethod {
    GET_STOCK(...) {...}, 
    GET_NEWS(...) {...};
    ...
}
```

Each enum class also has private members to deal with service API (different API for differenc sources)

And a variable of `ServiceMethod`

```
ServiceMethod method;
... // initializing
String cleanAndFancyData = method.queryData(); // e.g.
```

No I need to store user history, so I have to serialize and deserialize `ServiceMethod` variable and also enumerate all constants from all enums implementing this interface. The serialization looks simple and is out of question.

Now I just manually iterate over enums:

```
Collection<ServiceMethod> allMethods = new ArrayList<ServiceMethod>();
allMethods.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(ServiceA.class));
allMethods.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(ServiceB.class));
```

Is there a cleaner, nicer way for this? Or is my approach completely wrong?
Also, any way to ensure that all `ServiceMethod` have unique names (across all enums)?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the [*strategy pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to combine `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` into a single `Service`.